# How do I center an annotation title?

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a map with annotations that represent bikes. All of them have a title, an image, and a button. The title is on the left side by default as far as I can say. Is there any way I can center the title?

Comment: Hi i think it would help if you supply more information, what kind of map are you using? Maybe add a relevant snippet of your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the textAlignment to center

```
yourTitle.textAlignment = .center
```